# Prove that every bilinear associative form in a simple Lie algebra is a multiple of a Killing form

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra. I have to prove that if $L$ is a simple Lie algebra every bilinear associative form  (e.g. $([x,y],z)= (x,[y,z])$ for all $x,y,z \in L$) is a multiple of Killing form.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and progress that you've made so we can nudge you along...

Comment: Coul you give me some ideas?

Comment: What does $(\cdot,\cdot)$ mean here?  The Killing form?

Comment: @EricO.Korman That is a generic bilinear form.

Comment: What do you mean by 'associative' Lie algebra?

Comment: @EricO.Korman Sorry... I edited the question... the bilinear form is associative.

Comment: Lies and killing are bad....

Comment: In what sense...?

Comment: @goblin Wilhelm Killing indeed had a most unfortunate name for English speakers. I don't know how many times or years I have read his name, but it still jarrs a little. I think I still wince at the sight of "Killing fields" in DG (the 1980s film certainly gave me nightmares).

Comment: Note that the result is not true for those simple Lie algebras which are not absolutely simple (which can happen as soon as the field is not algebraically closed, e.g. over $\mathbb R$), cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3931433/96384. Note that the accepted answer to this question only deals with the algebraically closed case (which can then indeed be extended to that of absolutely simple Lie algebras).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proof below is based in the following statement which is valid (at least) for linear spaces $V$ over fields of characteristic $0$:

> If $(\cdot,\cdot)_1$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_2$ are nondegenerate bilinear forms on $V$ then there is a linear autormorphism $P\colon V\to V$ such that
> $$(v,w)_1=(Pv,w)_2,$$
> for all $v,w\in V$.

Also, we will also use (a consequence of) the Schur's Lemma:

> If $\rho\colon L\to\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a irreducible representation of the Lie Algebra $L$ (over a algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$) and $P\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is such that
> $$P\circ\rho(X) = \rho(X)\circ P,$$
> for every $X\in L$, then $P=\lambda I$ (where $I$ is the identity function) for some scalar $\lambda$.

I will assume (as we usually do when we talk about Killing form) that $L$ is a simple Lie algebra over a **algebraically closed** field of characteristic $0$. Now we begin the proof of the statement:

> Every bilinear and associative form $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $L$ is a multiple of the Killing form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $L$.

Firstly, we must note that
$$L^\perp:=\{X\in L\colon (X,Y)=0\text{ for all }Y\in L\}$$
is a ideal of $L$. In fact, given $X\in L^\perp$ and $Y\in L$, we have that
$$([X,Y],Z)=(X,[Y,Z])=0,$$
for every $Z\in L$, and, hence, $[X,Y]\in L^\perp$.

So, since $L$ is simple, $L^\perp=L$ or $0$. In the first case we already get the result because $L^\perp=L$ implies that $(\cdot,\cdot)=0$. So, in what follows, let us suppose that $L^\perp=0$. It means, that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is nondegenerate.

The bilinear forms $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ are nondegenerate (by the Cartan's Criterion of semisimplicity) on $L$. So, let $P\in\mathrm{GL}(L)$ be such that
$$(X,Y)=\langle P X,Y\rangle,$$
for every $X$ and $Y\in L$.

Next, we will show that
$$P\circ\mathrm{ad}(X)\circ P^{-1} =\mathrm{ad}(X),$$
for all $X\in L$. Then, we may conclude, from Schur's Lemma, that $P=\lambda I$, for some scalar $\lambda$ and, whence,
$$(X,Y)=\langle P X,Y\rangle = \lambda\langle X,Y\rangle,$$
for every $X$ and $Y\in L$. So, given $X\in L$, we have, for every $Y$ and $Z\in L$, that
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle P\circ\mathrm{ad}(X)\circ P^{-1}Y,Z\rangle & = & ([X,P^{-1}Y],Z) \\
& = & -([P^{-1}Y,X],Z) \\
& = & -(P^{-1}Y,[X,Z]) \\
& = & -\langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle \\
& = & -\langle [Y,X],Z\rangle \\
& = & \langle\mathrm{ad}(X)Y,Z\rangle.
\end{array}$$
Thus, since the Killing form on $L$ is non-degenerate, we have that $P\circ\mathrm{ad}(X)\circ P^{-1} =\mathrm{ad}(X)$, for all $X\in L$.

Comment: Is there a reference to this result? It looks like this was originally proved by Cartan, but I cannot find any reference for that.

Comment: Sorry, Max. I only know this result by lists of exercises (for example in San Martin's "Álgebras de Lie"). If you are interested to cite it in some text, I think it would be fair to call it "a well-known result on simple Lie algebras" and move on. But, of course, it is probably proved in some very old paper or some 'very friendly' introductory text on Lie algebras.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply! I will just say that this is a well-known result and move on. :)