# Find all invariant symmetric bilinear forms of $\mathfrak {sl}(2)$

Tags: lie-algebras, bilinear-form, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Find all invariant symmetric bilinear forms of $\mathfrak {sl}(2)$ (as defined in the previous exercise; assume that the field $k$ is of characteristic zero.)

Here is the exercise before it:

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $\rho: L \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ a finite-dimensional representation of L. Define a symmetric bilinear form on $L$ by $$\langle x, y \rangle_{\rho} = tr (\rho(x) \rho(y))$$
Where $\text{ tr }$ denotes the trace of endomorphisms.

$(a)$ Prove that this form is invariant, i.e., we have $$\langle [x,y], z \rangle_{\rho} = \langle x,[y,z] \rangle_{\rho}$$

for all $x,y,z \in L.$

**Some prior knowledge:**

I know that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(2) = L(M_2(k))$ of $2 \times 2$-matrices with complex entries is four-dimensional and that the four matrices $ X = \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{matrix}, Y= \begin{matrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0 
\end{matrix}, H = \begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1 
\end{matrix}, I = \begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{matrix}$ form a basis of $\mathfrak {gl}(2).$ Their commutators are $$[X,Y] = H, [H, X] = 2X, [H, Y] = -2Y,$$ and $$[I,X] = [I, Y] = [I, H] = 0. \quad \quad \quad (3.1)$$

The matrices of trace zero in $\mathfrak {gl}(2)$ form the subspace $\mathfrak {sl}(2)$ spanned by the basis $\{X, Y, H\}$ Relations $(3.1)$ show that $\mathfrak {sl}(2)$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak {gl}(2)$ and that there is an isomorphism of Lie algebras $$\mathfrak {gl}(2) \cong \mathfrak {sl}(2) \oplus kI.$$

Then I know also some information about the envelopping algebra $U$ of $\mathfrak {sl}(2).$

Still, I do not know how can I find all invariant symmetric bilinear forms of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ specifically I know that it is the subspace of all matrices of trace zero in $\mathfrak{gl}(2).$ Also, what is $\rho$ in my case here?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg you are correct ..... thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough that the field characteristic is $\ne 2$.

Let $\beta$ be an invariant symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$.
\begin{align}
0 &= \beta(h, 0) = \beta(h, [x,x]) = \beta([h, x], x) = \beta(2x, x)\\
0 &= \beta(h, 0) = \beta(h, [y,y]) = \beta([h, y], y) = \beta(-2y, y)\\
0 &= \beta(y, 0) = \beta(y, [x,x]) = \beta([y, x], x) = \beta(-h, x)\\
0 &= \beta(x, 0) = \beta(x, [y,y]) = \beta([x, y], y) = \beta(h, y)\\
\beta(2x, y) &= \beta([h, x], y) = \beta(h, [x,y]) = \beta(h, h)
\end{align}

So $\beta(x,x) = \beta(y,y) = \beta(h, x) = \beta(h, y) = 0$ and $\beta(h,h) = 2\beta(x,y)$.  Ordering the basis as $(x, h, y)$ and writing in a matrix, the matrix of $\beta$ is a scalar multiple of
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

and in fact, this is a valid invariant symmetric binlear form.  It's the one associated with $\text{tr}(\phi(x)\phi(y))$ where $\phi$ is the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ on a two dimensional space.

Comment: why it is enough that the field characteristic is not equal 2?

Comment: @Emptymind:  All you need to do for the proof to hold is divide by $2$ and $-1$ in several places.  The analysis is different if $2=0$ because then what you get from the equations is $\beta(h,x)=\beta(h,y)=\beta(h,h)=0$.

Comment: I do not know why I have to divide by only 2 and -1 in several places ..... why exactly those two numbers?

Comment: what is $\rho$ in our case here?

Comment: How are the matrices of trace zero reflected in your solution?

Comment: why the invariant symmetric bilinear form is given by a matrix here in our case? and why this matrix does not have trace zero?

Comment: in the first question of my previous comment I meant why it is a $3\times 3$ matrix and not a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: I believe that by $\phi (x)$ you mean the matrix of $X$ I gave in my question above ..... am I correct?

Comment: Also, I believe that, in your notation  $\beta(x,x)$ means $\operatorname{tr}(\phi(x) \phi(x) )$ .... am I correct?

Comment: From where comes the one in the top right and bottom left entries of the matrix $\beta$?

Comment: The $3$-by-$3$ matrix is giving the values of the bilinear form on pairs of basis elements $\{x,h,y\}$ (it is sometimes called the "Gram matrix" of the bilinear form. It is a symmetric matrix if the form is symmetric. What John Doe is doing is showing that if $\beta$ is an invariant bilinear form, then its values are completely determined by that condition (up to a scalar -- if $\beta$ is an invariant for then clearly $c.\beta$ is an invariant form for any scalar $c$)....

Comment: His calculations show 4 of the 6 entries of on or above the diagonal of the Gram matrix must be zero, and the remaining two satisfy $2\beta(x,y) = \beta(h,h)$, hence he sets $\beta(x,y)=1$ to get the 3-by-3 matrix shown. The only thing he uses is the assumption that $2\neq 0$, i.e. $\text{char}(\mathsf k) \neq 0$, but he uses it 3 times -- in the 1st, 2nd and 5th line of his calculation. If $\text{char}(\mathsf k)=2$, then the first two identities become trivial, while the third becomes $\beta(h,h)=0$, and in fact in this case the space of invariant symmetric bilinear forms is 3-dimensional.

Comment: @krm2233 but I think he found the matrix of the bilinear forms not "all invariant symmetric bilinear forms" am I correct? if so, how we can then find all invariant symmetric bilinear forms?

Comment: @krm2233  what are the correct logical steps in the solution? are we supposed to calculate the matrix first using the given definition of a bilinear form and then show that each one of them is invariant? but how did he show that those are **all** the invariant bilinear forms?

Comment: If you can write down the Gram matrix of a bilinear form, you completely determine it, so if you can describe the possible Gram matrices of invariant bilinear forms, then you determine all the possible invariant bilinear forms. What John Doe does is use the invariance condition (assuming $\text{char}(\mathsf k)=0$) to show that the entries of the Gram matrix are all uniquely determined once you chose a value for $\beta(x,y)$, thus all possible Gram matrices are scalar multiples of the one he writes out... to be continued.

Comment: The final thing to do is to show that the Gram matrix John Doe writes down really gives an invariant symmetric bilinear form $b$ say. Since $\dim(\mathfrak{sl}_2)=3$, you could just check by hand that it satisfies the invariance property (you only need to do this for elements of a basis, so there are 27 identities to check). However, an alternative approach is to just exhibit *any* non-zero invariant symmetric bilinear form, $t$, as any such $t$ must be a non-zero multiple of the form $b$.  But $t(x,y) = \text{tr}(xy)$ is a nonzero invariant symmetric bilinear form, and so we are done!

Comment: I did not get what exactly done to show that the matrix $\beta$ describe **invariant** symmetric bilinear form ...... could you clarify this please? ..... note that I know why it describes symmetric bilinear form. @krm2233

Comment: I also have the following question, why he calculated $\beta(h,0)$ by this way? I uusually calculate it by the definition given in the question (the one using the trace function)

Comment: what are the 27 identities that is needed to be checked?

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at this is to use the fact that a symmetric bilinear form $B\colon  V\times V \to \mathsf k$ gives a linear map $\theta\colon V \to V^*$ by setting $\theta_B(v)\in V^*$ to be the functional $\theta(v)(w) = B(v,w)$. In the case where $V$ is a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and the symmetric bilinear form $B$ is invariant, then a straight-forward computation shows that $\theta_B\colon \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g^*$ is an homomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-representations.

Write $\mathfrak g$ (or $\mathfrak g(\mathsf k)$ if we need to be clear which field we are using) for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$.

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak g(\mathsf k)$ is simple, or equivalently the adjoint representation is irreducible, whenever $\mathsf k$ has characteristic not equal to $2$. To see this, suppose that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ and $I\neq 0$, then we may pick $a \in I\backslash \{0\}$. Write $a = \lambda_1X+\lambda_2 Y +\lambda_3H$.
Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
[X,[H,a]] = [X,2\lambda_1X -2\lambda_2Y] = -2\lambda_2H,\\
[H,[X,a]] =[H, \lambda_2H - 2\lambda_3X] = -4\lambda_3X, \\
[Y,[H,a]] = Y,2\lambda_1X-2\lambda_2Y] = -2\lambda_1H.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since at least one of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\neq 0$, we must have either $H \in I$ or $X\in I$. But then it is easy to see from the identities $[X,Y]=H, [H,X]=2X$ and $[H,Y]=-2Y$ that if $X$ or $H$ lie in $I$, then all of $X,Y,H$ lie in $I$ so that $I =\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ is simple as required. (Note that it is the appearance of $2$ in the relations $[H,X]=2X$ and $[H,Y]=-2Y$ which make characteristic $2$ an exception. See below for more on that case.)

Now since $\mathfrak g(\mathsf k)$ is simple, Schur's Lemma shows that $D=\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak g}(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g^*)$ is a division algebra. Since the only division algebra over an algebraically closed field is the field itself, this means that if $\mathsf k$ is algebraically closed, the space of invariant bilinear forms is at most $1$-dimensional.

In fact because we know $\mathfrak{sl}_2(F)$ is simple for any field $F$ of characteristic different from $2$ (and so in particular for $\bar{\mathsf k}$ if $\text{char}(\mathsf k)\neq 2$) this bound holds for any such $\mathsf k$. Indeed $\bar{\mathsf k}\otimes_{\mathsf k} D \cong \bar{\mathsf k}^d$ were $d = \dim_{\mathsf k}(D)$ and $\bar{\mathsf k}\otimes_{\mathsf k}\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k}) = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\bar{\mathsf k})$. But then

$$
\bar{\mathsf k}^d = \bar{\mathsf k}\otimes_{\mathsf k}D = 
\bar{\mathsf k}\otimes \text{Hom}_{\mathfrak g}(\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g^*) \subseteq \text{Hom}_{\mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k})}(\mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k}), \mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k})^*)
$$
and the space $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k})}(\mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k}), \mathfrak g(\bar{\mathsf k})^*)$ is at most one-dimensional since $\bar{\mathsf k}$ is algebraically closed, so $d\leq 1$.

Since the trace form $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}(x,y) = \text{tr}(xy)$ is readily checked to be a nonzero invariant *symmetric* bilinear form, the space of all symmetric invariant bilinear forms must be $\mathsf k.t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ and moreover it also follows that $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ is nondegenerate! (This can be checked directly from the explicit calcuation of $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ in John Doe's answer.)

If $\text{char}(\mathsf k)=2$, the story is completely different: in that case $[H,X]=0, [H,Y]=0$ and $[X,Y] = Z$, so that $\text{span}_{\mathsf k}\{H\}=D(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)) = \mathfrak z(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k))$, and so $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ is no longer simple. In fact $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k) \cong \mathfrak n_3(\mathsf k)$ where $\mathfrak n_3(\mathsf k)$ is the space of strictly upper-triangular $3$-by-$3$ matrices over $\mathsf k$, the smallest nonabelian nilpotent Lie algebra over $\mathsf k$.

Moreover, it is easy to see that the trace form $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ is now degenerate, because in characteristic 2 $I_2=H \in\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ and $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}(I_2,a)=\text{tr}(I_2.a)=\text{tr}(a)=0$ for all $a \in \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ (and in fact $\mathsf k.I_2$ is the radical of $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ as again you can check by explicit calculation). Indeed it is easy enough to check that $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ and its dual $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)^*$ are not in fact isomorphic as $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$-representations, and so that there are no nondegenerate symmetric bilinear forms on $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathsf k)$ in this case. On the other hand, the space of invariant bilinear forms, or equivalently the space $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g^*)$ is now $4$-dimensional! If we write $\{\delta_X,\delta_H,\delta_Y\}$ for the basis of $\mathfrak g^*$ dual to $\{X,H,Y\}$, then the invariant bilinear forms are spanned by $\text{span}\{\delta_X.\delta_X,\delta_X.\delta_Y,\delta_Y.\delta_X,\delta_Y.\delta_Y \in \{X,Y\}\}$, where $\delta_a.\delta_b$ denotes the bilinear map $(x,y)\mapsto \delta_a(x).\delta_b(y)$. The trace form $t_{\mathfrak{sl}_2}$ is just $\delta_X.\delta_Y + \delta_Y.\delta_X$. Note that it is invariant symmetric bilinear form which is *not* alternating. (In characteristic $2$, symmetric and skew-symmetric mean the same thing, but the alternating condition is strictly stronger.)

I can't help adding a general remark about invariant bilinear forms: the notion of an "invariant" bilinear form is often introduced as the condition that $B([x,y],z) = B(x,[y,z])$ without explanation (or worse, it is called "associativity") but it is just the usual notion of invariance, i.e. that the span of $B$ gives a copy of the trivial representation: Bilinear forms on a $\mathfrak g$-representation $V$ have the structure of a $\mathfrak g$-representation because they can be identified with the space $(V\otimes V)^*$. The calculation that checks that $\theta_B$ is a homomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-representations if $B$ is invariant in fact shows that the map $B \mapsto \theta_B$ from bilinear forms on $V$ to $\text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,V^*)$ is a homomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-representations, which makes it clear why this works -- the calculation reduces to the one for $\mathfrak{gl}_V$ acting on $V$ and in that case it follows from the fact that the identification of the space of bilinear forms with $\text{Hom}(V,V^*)$ is functorial.

Comment: Simplicity of a Lie algebra and/or Schur's Lemma in general do not suffice to conclude that the space of symmetric invariant forms is one-dimensional. For example, take any simple complex LA and consider it, via scalar restriction, as a real LA: It is simple, but the space of invariant forms on it has real dimension $2$. One needs that the Lie algebra is *absolutely* simple i.e. stays simple under any (algebraic) scalar extension. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3931433/96384

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right -- I had for some reason assumed that the question was working over an algebraically closed field, but it only assumed the $\mathsf k$ was characteristic zero. I've editted the answer to spell out what needs to be added if you do not assume $\mathsf k$ is algebraically closed.