# Trace of irreducible representations and Cartan-Killing metric

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a semisimple and compact Lie algebra $L$ generated by a certain number of elements $\{t_i\}$ the Cartan-Killing metric is defined as:
$$k_{ij} \equiv tr(ad_{t_i}ad_{t_j})$$
where $ad_{t_i}$ is the adjoint representation of $t_i$ and the metric is nonsingular and negative definite.

In chapter 15 of the Penskin (An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory) it is written that for every irreducible representation $t^r_i$ of $t_i$ we have that:
$$tr(t^r_it^r_j) = c_rtr(ad_{t_i}ad_{t_j})$$
and thus we can compute the Cartan Killing metric in any irreducible representation up to a multiplicative factor $c_r$ which depends on the representation.

I tried to look for a proof of this equality but couldn't find anything. Could someone tell me where it comes from even without giving the complete proof?

Comment: If the adjoint representation is irreducible then $L$ is simple as a Lie algebra. Then [every bilinear invariant form is a multiple of the Killing form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298287/prove-that-every-bilinear-associative-form-in-a-simple-lie-algebra-is-a-multiple) by Schur's Lemma.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't seen the post you kindly linked to me